# FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON not undimming the screen

Tags: android, screen, wakelock, keyguard

I'm using the following line of code on the `onCreate()` methods of my two activities:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

The point of course, is to keep the screen turned on and undimmed.

The point is that if the screen is dimmed -not turned off- before one of my activities is launched, the screen will maintain it's dimming until the user touchs the activity. After the user interacts in any way (TouchEvent or something like that, I'm assuming) with the activity the device will undimm the screen and maintain it that way until the user leaves the activity.

Does anyone knows why this is happening and how can I undimm the screen of the device before setting the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag?

Comment: "The point of course, is to keep the screen turned on and undimmed" -- note that the name of the flag is `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, not `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON_AND_UNDIMMED`. "Does anyone knows why this is happening" -- I would presume that it is happening by design.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have any other alternatives? I wanted to use a wake lock but it says on Android's documentation never to use a wake lock on an activity.

Comment: IMHO, the right answer is to leave it alone. Beyond that, the only way I can think of to get what you want is to briefly use a `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`, just enough to get the screen to undim, before `release()`-ing that `WakeLock`. This will require you to hold the `WAKELOCK` permission.

Comment: @CommonsWare Regarding the FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag, the documentation states the folloging: **as long as this window is visible to the user, keep the device's screen turned on and bright.** So I was correct in my assumption. It should work just by setting the flag. Also, accquiring a wake lock had the same effect as the flag.

Comment: "So I was correct in my assumption. It should work just by setting the flag" -- that is not how I would interpret the documentation.